# Spring security4 "Access denied " issues, authoritiesByUsernameQuery doesn't work?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a table agents with : **[id primary key, email varchar, password varchar]**

and agents_roles table : **[agent_role_id primary key, email varchar, agent_id foreign key]**

In my Security controller i have this :

```
@Configuration

@EnableWebSecurity

public class Security extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

     @Autowired
     private DataSource dataSource;

     @Override
     protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception 
     {

            auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                             .usersByUsernameQuery("select email, password,visibility from agents where email=?")
                             .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select email, role from agents_roles where email=?");
      }

      @Override
      protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http.formLogin().loginPage("/login");

         http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN");

           http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/agent/**").hasRole("DEV");

           http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");

     }

}
```

When i try to get the home page a get the access denied page "403.html" !

I think the second query "authoritiesByUsernameQuery" doesn't work correctly but i don't know why ?

I tried an other example with users table and users_role and it work fine but the difference is the username is the primary key !!

Help please and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem !

Here in my query i use this and it worked fine  :

```
 ....
 usersByUsernameQuery("select a.email as username, a.password, a.visibility from agents a where a.email=?")
                             .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select ar.email as username, ar.role from agents_roles ar, agents a where a.id = ar.agent_id and ar.email=?");
 ....
```